# How to detect the intensity gradient direction

Tags: c++, opencv

Having a Mat that is square area of grayscale pixels. How to create a straight line whose direction is created as a perpendicular to most pixel values change direction (average gradient, aerage over the whole Mat, the result would be just one direction (which can be then drawn as a line))?

For example having

[image]

it would look like

[image]

How can one do such thing in OpenCV (in python or C++)?

Comment: sounds just like the average gradient...

Comment: I see that the picture is almost uniform pixels. What pixels do you mean?

Comment: Please, define "perpendicular to a pixel value".

Comment: It is also not clear to me, what you perform the average over:
Option 1: If you vaerage over the whole picture, the result woulb be just one direction (which can be then drawn as a line)
Option 2: If you average over a line in your picture, you get N directions (corresponding to a wiggly line, like the one you drew).
Option 3: If you average over one column of the picture -> analogue option 2
Let us know, what you want

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An OpenCV implementation would look something like the following. It solves the problem in a similar fashion as explained in the answer by Mark Setchell, except that normalising the image does not have any effect on the resulting direction.

```
Mat img = imread("img.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// compute the image derivatives for both the x and y direction
Mat dx, dy;
Sobel(img, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
Sobel(img, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1);

Scalar average_dx = mean(dx);
Scalar average_dy = mean(dy);

double average_gradient = atan2(-average_dy[0], average_dx[0]);
cout << "average_gradient = " << average_gradient << endl;
```

And to display the resulting direction

```
Point center = Point(img.cols/2, img.rows/2);
Point direction = Point(cos(average_gradient) * 100, -sin(average_gradient) * 100);

Mat img_rgb = imread("img.png"); // read the image in colour
line(img_rgb, center, center + direction, Scalar(0,0,255));
imshow("image", img_rgb);
waitKey();
```

[image: image direction]

Comment: Nice one - well done! I agree about the normalisation - I mainly did that for visualisation purposes because a couple of comments on the original question implied folks couldn't see what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I can't easily tell you how to do it with **OpenCV**, but I can tell you the method and demonstrate using **ImageMagick** just at the command-line.

First, I think you need to convert the image to grayscale and normalise it to the full range of black to white - like this:

```
convert gradient.png -colorspace gray -normalize stage1.png
```

[image]

Then you need to calculate the X-gradient and the Y-gradient of the image using a Sobel filter and then take the inverse tan of the Y-gradient over the X-gradient:

```
convert stage1.png -define convolve:scale='50%!' -bias 50% \
  \( -clone 0 -morphology Convolve Sobel:0 \) \
  \( -clone 0 -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 \) \
  -fx '0.5+atan2(v-0.5,0.5-u)/pi/2' result.jpg
```

Then the mean value of the pixels in `result.jpg` is the direction of your line.

You can see the coefficients used in the convolution for X- and Y-gradient like this:

```
convert xc: -define morphology:showkernel=1 -morphology Convolve Sobel:0 null:

Kernel "Sobel" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from -2 to 2
Forming a output range from -4 to 4 (Zero-Summing)
 0:         1         0        -1
 1:         2         0        -2
 2:         1         0        -1


convert xc: -define morphology:showkernel=1 -morphology Convolve Sobel:90 null:
Kernel "Sobel@90" of size 3x3+1+1 with values from -2 to 2
Forming a output range from -4 to 4 (Zero-Summing)
 0:         1         2         1
 1:         0         0         0
 2:        -1        -2        -1
```

See Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) - specifically this line:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Convert the image to grayscale and classify its pixels based on the gray level. For classification, you can use something like Otsu method or kmeans with 2 clusters. Then take the morphological gradient to detect the doundary.

Here are the classified pixels and the boundary using Otsu method.

[image: otsu]
[image: boundaty]

Now find the non-zero pixels of the boundary image and fit a 2D line to those pixels using the fitLine function that finds a weighted least squares line or use [this](https://github.com/srinath1905/GRANSAC) RANSAC implementation. fitLine gives a normalized vector collinear to the line. Using this vector, you can find an orthogonal vector to it.

I get `[0.983035, -0.183421]` for the collinear vector using the code below. So, `[0.183421 0.983035]` is orthogonal to this vector.

Here, in the left image, the red line is the least squares line and the blue line is a perpendicular line to the red one. In the right image, red line is the least squares line and the green one is the line fitted using the RANSAC library mentioned above.

[image: lsq]
[image: ransac]

```
Mat im = imread("LP24W.png", 0);

Mat bw, gr;

threshold(im, bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);

Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
morphologyEx(bw, gr, CV_MOP_GRADIENT, kernel);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(gr, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
vector<Point> points;
for (vector<Point>& cont: contours)
{
    points.insert(points.end(), cont.begin(), cont.end());
}
Vec4f line;
fitLine(points, line, CV_DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
cout << line << endl;
```